# Is there an IntersectionObserver alternative to detect visibility for iframe/WebView content?

Tags: javascript, iframe, webview

I need to display various user generated content my web/apps using `iframe`/`WebView`. The same URL should be used by all platforms. Meaning, web, Android app and iOS app. I want to be able to track if it is visible at least one pixel and at least 50%.

Is there an alternative to `IntersectionObserver` that could be used in this scenario? Or maybe there is some other approach?

I tried using `IntersectionObserver` in this demo [codepen](https://codepen.io/donkarolel/pen/PoxPJOx) and it works beautifully when rendered by an `iframe`. However, in a `WebView` both callbacks are fired right away, despite it not being in a viewport yet.